# When my object is no longer referenced why do its events continue to run?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, publish-subscribe

Say I am making a game and have a base `Buff` class. I may also have a subclass named `ThornsBuff` which subscribes to the `Player` class's `Damaged` event.

The `Player` may have a list of `Buff`s and one of them may be the `ThornsBuff`. For example:

### Test Class

```
Player player = new Player();
player.ActiveBuffs.Add(new ThornsBuff(player));
```

### ThornsBuff Class

```
public ThornsBuff(Player player)
{
    player.DamageTaken += player_DamageTaken;
}

private void player_DamageTaken(MessagePlayerDamaged m)
{
    m.Assailant.Stats.Health -= (int)(m.DamageAmount * .25);
}
```

This is all to illustrate an example. If I were to remove the buff from the list, the event is not detached. Even though the player no longer has the buff, the event is still executed as if he did.

Now, I could have a `Dispel` method to unregister the event, but that forces the developer to call `Dispel` in addition to removing the `Buff` from the list. What if they forget, increased coupling, etc.

What I don't understand is why the event doesn't detach itself automatically when the `Buff` is removed from the list. The `Buff` only existed in the list and that is its one reference. After it is removed shouldn't the event be detached?

I tried adding the detaching code to the finalizer of the `Buff` but that didn't fix it either. The event is still running even after it has 0 references. I suppose it is because the garbage collector had not run yet? Is there any way to make it automatic and instant so that when the object has no references all its events are unregistered?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like Weak Event Pattern: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx)
The behavior you noticed can be the source of memory leaks for the same reason: the object won't be deleted until you manually detach it from the event

Comment: Weak events would work *eventually* but my understanding it that the event would continue to get called until the GC collects it, which in the case of a real-time game might be too late.  He probably wants the buff to stop occurring **immediately** when it's removed from the list.

Comment: @DanielCastro: Yeah I was looking in to weak events but getting them to work *right* in C# seems to take some work. Also, when they are removed from the list the buffs would have to be **immediately** removed, as Kael Rowan said. I'd imagine that as a result weak events would not be usable.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not sure if you have to wait until the GC collects it, I don't think so, but as I said, I'm not sure.
About implementation, apart from the link I already posted, if you're using WPF, many mvvm toolkits have something like that. For example, MVVM Light has a Messenger class for weak events. And it's easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event (player_DamageTaken) will continue to be called regardless of whether the Buff is in the ActiveBuffs list or not.  This is because when you run DamageTaken += player_DamageTaken then it creates a reference from player.DamageTaken to **that instance of ThornsBuff** and its player_DamageTaken method.  (Otherwise, how would the runtime know which instance of ThornsBuff to call player_DamageTaken on?)

That reference will continue to exist until you call player.DamageTaken **-**= player_DamageTaken.  The fact that you **also** add the Buff to ActiveBuffs simply adds *another* reference to the buff, which isn't technically necessary (but it's good form in my opinion since I don't like having non-referenced event handlers hanging around).

Now you're probably wondering how to remove the event handler without causing the developer to call an extra Dispel or Dispose method, and for that here are some suggestions:

1. At the beginning of player_DamageTaken do a check to see if player.ActiveBuffs.Contains(this), and if not, call player.DamageTaken -= player_DamageTaken and return.  The disadvantage to this is that you're searching the entire list of Buffs every time they take damage.
2. Make ActiveBuffs an ObservableCollection (or something similar) that can listen for when buffs are removed from the list.  When they are, you can call buff.Dispel automatically so that the developer doesn't have to remember to call it.

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd have to go the route of making a custom collection. I probably would have had to do it anyway considering an `Update` function on the list to refresh all the buff durations would be nice. Also, something as important as the list of buffs would need more features. I suppose inheriting from `IEnumerable` would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is why the event doesn't detatch itself automatically when the Buff is removed from the list.

Because attaching the Buff to the list was not what attached the event. The event was attached because you attached it in the constructor. The player class instance now also has a reference to that buff in it's DamangeTake event, and so removing it from the Buffs list is not enough to allow the object to be garbage collected... therefore the buff lives on.

One wonders why you use events here at all. Why not just have code in the player that iterates through each buff in the list and runs some method defined as part of the interface, with the damage as argument or return value. That would do more what you're looking for.

Alternatively, everywhere you currently remove a buff you will also need code to unsubscribe it's event.

Comment: I just prefer event based programming. When the player is hit it raises an event that he or she was hit. Instead of having all the potential code in that one method, have relevant classes subscribe to the `PlayerDamaged` event and perform appropriate logic upon such an event. I'm not sure how to implement what you're talking about with something like a Thorns buff.